# rmmod on mac80211 module is crashing

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography, wireless, cryptographic-hash-function

rmmod on mac80211 module (With my changes in ieee80211_init()) is
crashing. I dont have any changes in ieee80211_exit(). However, there is a crash observed on     ieee80211_exit() for freeing mesh table, tbl. How come my changes in init function would cause a problem in exit function? Without
my changes, there is no problem with unloading the module.

If I comment out statement to call hmac_sha512(), then
rmmod gets succeeded. If I integrate this code to a custom module like
Hello, then there is no problem with rmmod. If it is a synchronization
issue, then how come there is no issue with Hello module?
I have pasted the code of the function, hmac_sha512() and other related functions below.
I have tried sync APIs too. Same issue is reproducible even then.

Have dived deep into the mac80211 functionality and found out that the issue is caused by mesh table de-
allocation. Prior to de-allocation, Mesh table has to be allocated by ieee80211s_start() in order to get de-
allocated  ieee80211s_stop(). Have put logs in the code to check who is allocating the mesh table from mac80211; as per the logs, there is no one(including HMAC code) from mac80211 allocating  the mesh table.

If I comment out the below lines from ieee80211_exit(), rmmod works fine:

```
/*

If(mesh_allocated)
    ieee80211_stop;

*/
```

Please provide some pointers for resolving this issue.

```
#define HMAC_SHA512_SIZE 64

struct hmac_sha512_result {
    struct completion completion;
    int err;
};

static void hmac_sha512_complete(struct crypto_async_request *req, int err) {
    struct hmac_sha512_result *r=req->data;
    if(err==-EINPROGRESS)
        return;
    r->err=err;
    complete(&r->completion);
}

int hmac_sha512(const unsigned char *key, // key 
                         const unsigned char *data_in, // data in
                        unsigned char *hash_out, size_t outlen) {  // hash buffer and length

    int rc=0;
    struct crypto_ahash *tfm;
    struct scatterlist sg;
    struct ahash_request *req;
    struct hmac_sha512_result tresult;
    void *hash_buf;
        size_t klen = strlen(key);
        size_t dlen = strlen(data_in); 

        int len = HMAC_SHA512_SIZE;
        char hash_tmp[HMAC_SHA512_SIZE];
    char *hash_res = hash_tmp;

        printk(KERN_INFO "hmac_sha512: HMAC key is %s ", key);

    /* Set hash output to 0 initially */
    memset(hash_out, 0, outlen);

    init_completion(&tresult.completion);
    tfm=crypto_alloc_ahash("hmac(sha512)",0,0);
    if(IS_ERR(tfm)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: crypto_alloc_ahash failed.\n");
        rc=PTR_ERR(tfm);
        goto err_tfm;
    }
    if(!(req=ahash_request_alloc(tfm,GFP_KERNEL))) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: failed to allocate request for hmac(sha512)\n");
        rc=-ENOMEM;
        goto err_req;
    }
    if(crypto_ahash_digestsize(tfm)>len) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: tfm size > result buffer.\n");
        rc=-EINVAL;
        goto err_req;
    }
    ahash_request_set_callback(req,CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG,
                    hmac_sha512_complete,&tresult);

    if(!(hash_buf=kzalloc(dlen,GFP_KERNEL))) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: failed to kzalloc hash_buf");
        rc=-ENOMEM;
        goto err_hash_buf;
    }
    memcpy(hash_buf,data_in,dlen);
    sg_init_one(&sg,hash_buf,dlen);

    crypto_ahash_clear_flags(tfm,-0);
    if((rc=crypto_ahash_setkey(tfm,key,klen))){
        printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: crypto_ahash_setkey failed\n");
        goto err_setkey;
    }
    ahash_request_set_crypt(req,&sg,hash_res,dlen);
    rc=crypto_ahash_digest(req);
    switch(rc) {
        case 0:
            while (len--) {
                snprintf(hash_out, outlen, "%02x", (*hash_res++ & 0x0FF));
                hash_out += 2;
            }

                break;
        case -EINPROGRESS:
        case -EBUSY:
            rc=wait_for_completion_interruptible(&tresult.completion);
            if(!rc && !(rc=tresult.err)) {
                INIT_COMPLETION(tresult.completion);
                break;
            } else {
                printk(KERN_ERR "hmac_sha512: wait_for_completion_interruptible failed\n");
                goto out;
            }
        default:
            goto out;
    }

    out:
    err_setkey:
        kfree(hash_buf);
    err_hash_buf:
        ahash_request_free(req);
    err_req:
        crypto_free_ahash(tfm);
    err_tfm:
        return rc;
}
```

Comment: A quick review makes me think this hang may be due to the way your completion synchronization is being managed.  If you comment out the completion calls (for diagnosing) does it still hang?

Comment: I commented out the call, ahash_request_set_callback. Hmac_sha512 Call is returned successfully. However, rmmod is hanged up, still. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can review successful use of these crypto calls in the kernel here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/ Just search for one of the simpler examples of how something like ahash_request_set_crypt() is used.

Comment: I have tried sync APIs too. Same issue is reproducible even then.